# Is child_removed guaranteed to have the latest data?

Tags: firebase, concurrency, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase and I'm wondering whether I can rely on the `DataSnapshot` passed via a `child_removed` event to be the canonical final value before removal or whether it could be an intermediary value.

In the docs for `child_removed` it says

> The DataSnapshot passed into the callback will be the old data for the
>   child that was removed.

But in the docs for `child_changed` it says

> Note that a single child_changed event may represent multiple changes
>   to the child

So I am wondering if there was a sequence of 100 changes and a removal of the node in very quick succession if the snapshot passed to `child_removed` will be guaranteed to be the final state of the node or only *some* state from the last time the client received an update of the value.

The reason I ask is because my server is setup to remove a value once some criteria is met. But I also want my clients to know the status of that final state before removal even if they have more latency than my server and haven't yet received the update before the server removes the value.

Comment: It will always represent the order in which removal and changes had been sent to Firebase. So if you make an amount of `x` changes to a node and try to delete it afterwards it will always have the value of the `x.` change you made. Firebase will operate in the order it receives commands.

Comment: Yes but say you set the value to X, Y, Z, then null. I know you're not guaranteed to get a child_changed for X, Y, and Z (I could get X and Z, for instance). Is the child_removed event similar to child_changed where it may skip the Z state? Or is that always guaranteed to get through to every client regardless of latency?